# Inject JavaScript files inside Templates or HTML with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, gulp

Let's say I have a server (Node & Express for example) which serves HTML pages to clients based on templates files (as pug, ejs, handlebars, twig, marko...). It's a classical multi pages website where each page has it's own JavaScript files. If I use webpack to bundle JavaScript files, is it possible to inject automatically (with the build step) Javascript files into their corresponding templates ?

I don't want to generate HTML files, so every *html-webpack-plugin* based solutions are not what i am searching. I want to do like i can do with grunt or gulp, but with webpack to don't have to import each bundle manually in each corresponding template.

Example of solutions without webpack :

[gulp inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)

[post build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postbuild)

I don't find real answers in other posts.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

It kind of works. I tried with pug and then with marko based on SpeedOfRound answer. I had a problem to inject files because my templates are nested (layout, wrapper, page...) and i didn't have `head` or `body` in files where i wanted to place my tags. I used `inject: false` and `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags %>` (only available in v4.0 +) and it works, but not exactly what i expected. Here we are creating a new file in `./dist/` and it doesn't follow my architecture. I just want to make a bundle by template and inject it in the right template automatically.

After, the final goal would be to just create JS files in the right folder where a template view lives and then it would be automatically inject to this view (in the convention over configuration way).

Comment: To clarify, you have *existing* html templates that you want your js builds injected into?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound Yes

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` by pointing it to your template.
Heres my abridged `webpack.config.js` where I do this with mustache templates.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: "./js/app.js",
  },  
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename:'[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'React': 'react',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: 'head',
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './templates/dist/app.mustache'),
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./templates/app.mustache"),
      chunks: ['entry'],
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico"
    }),
  ]
}
```

This is very useful for code splitting, where you can split your builds into chunks and inject multiple chunks into your pages. That way you can reuse chunks and the browser only has to load them once between pages.

It dosn't have to be mustache, I also do this with php views.

Comment: Thank you. It's close to what i wanted. I edited my post to give more details.

Comment: The idea is you use the generated templates in `/dist` in your actual application, while your original ones are the ones you develop on. Your original ones can't be modified because then they would change ever build, and you'd have to commit the changes every time. You would also be accumulating your injections, since the previous one would be saved from last time.

Comment: I understood that, but it doesn't really answer my needs. I would like to just inject bundle files to my actual template.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do that. If you don't include `chunkhash` in your output name, you can just hard code the path into your template. The file gets updated every time you build but the name stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question was asked 2 years ago so you probably solved the problem. However I spent the last few days trying to figure this out! Here's my solution in case anyone has the same issue:

Use `html-webpack-pug-plugin` along with your `html-webpack-plugin`.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPugPlugin = require('html-webpack-pug-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    home: "./src/index.js",
  },
  output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"),
     filename: "[name].js",
     publicPath: "/public",
     clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./views/_head.pug",
      filename: "../views/head.pug",
      minify: false,
      inject: "head",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

You should only call `HtmlWebpackPugPlugin` once as said in the documentation
https://github.com/negibouze/html-webpack-pug-plugin#usage

For code to be injected, the template `_head.pug` needs to have a `body` tag so that code gets injected
For the code to be indented properly, it also needs to have a `html` tag

`_head.pug`:

```
doctype html
html
  head

  body
```

After building:
head.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(defer src="/public/home.js")
    link(href="/public/home.css" rel="stylesheet")

  body
```

If anyone is confused, `home.css` is imported in `index.js` (classic webpack magic)